# Switch axes on .fig matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, swap, figure, axes

While editing a .fig matlab file, I want to swap the x and y axes without redrawing the plot by code (without changing the order of vector data). Does a solution exist to my problem? Is there some option in the figure properties menu? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Luis 's answer you can set the current axes `View` property to `[90 -90]` directly from the property inspector.

Programmatically this is equivalent to this:

```
set(gca,'View',[90 -90])
```

Note:

Thanks to Luis for the correction. Using `[-90 90]` does swap the axis but then you need to reverse the direction of the y-axis. Therefore it's better to use `[90 -90]`.

Simple example:

Before swap:

[image]

And then after changing the view:

[image]

Comment: I was about to add that! That's the preferred approach I think

Comment: But I think you need `[90 -90]` (not `[-90 90]`). That way the _x_ axis increases to the right (not to the left)

Comment: Ah yes you're right! With `[-90 90]`  one would need to reverse the direction of the y-axis. Thanks! And +1 as well your solution is very handy.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly access the `'XData'` and `'YData'` properties of each plot and swap them:

```
c = get(gca,'children'); %// get children of axes
for n = 1:numel(children); %// for each children
    set(c(n),'XData',get(c(n),'YData'),'YData',get(c(n),'XData')); %// swap XData, YData
end
```